# Vim go to next search result across multiple files?

Tags: vim, vi

When I use source insight before, when I search for some word I can press the "search forward" button to jump to next match *across all project files*.

For example:

1. Search "apple"
2. Source Insight list all project contain "apple" word (ex: 15 result )
3. Press "search forward button"
4. Cursor jumps to next search result, repeat as needed to see all 15 results

But using vim with cscope, I need something like:

1. :cs find s "apple"
2. cscope list 15 result
3. input "1" and jump to first result
4. :cs find s "apple"
5. cscope list 15 result
6. input "2" and jump to second result

It's very complex.

Is there a better way to do this in Vim?

Comment: If  it is only one file, you could use / instead of using cscope

Answer (score 11):

Vim allows you to redirect cscope's output to the quickfix window with the `'cscopequickfix'` option. Below is the suggested value in `:help 'cscopequickfix'`:

```
set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
```

From there, you can search for `apple` with:

```
:cs f s apple
```

view the list of matches with:

```
:cw[indow]
```

jump to the next match with:

```
:cn[ext]
```

jump to the previous match with:

```
:cp[revious]
```

and, of course, use the mouse or the keyboard to select entries in the quickfix window.

Bonus: add this to your `vimrc` to skip the `:cwindow` step:

```
augroup qf
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * cwindow
augroup END
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, you can use [`:vimgrep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:vimgrep) [`:copen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:copen) and [`:cnext`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:cnext):

1. Search underlying directories for "apple"

   `:vim apple **`
2. Show all 15 results:

   `:cope`
3. Jump to `n`-ext result:

   `:cn`

To make jumping between results easier, I have the following in [my .vimrc](https://github.com/johnsyweb/dotfiles/blob/9dd9cd/.vimrc#L230-L233):

```
noremap    <F4>   :<C-U>cnext <CR>
noremap    <S-F4> :<C-U>cprevious <CR>
```

For more information, see:

- [`:help quickfix`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html)
- [`:help noremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'noremap')

Comment: In other words: do you really need cscope? If not, try Vim's internal "find in files" feature.

Answer (score 0):

In vim (command mode) you can use `/apple` to search search for the word `apple`. Then use `n` to search forward and `N` to search backward.

You can set a few settings to make it better as well

```
:set incsearch # will jump to the search work as you type
:set hlsearch # will highlight all matches
:set ignorecase # will use case insensitive searches
:set smartcase # will use case sensitive search if the search word contains capitals
```

EDIT:

@johnsyweb has the correct answer would be to use [vimgrep](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim)

Comment: i want search all project file,not only this file

Comment: @CKvir: Then my answer should help!